# Parse content from a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need to dynamically update contents in a div of main page, based on data fetched from other html page

```
setInterval( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:"url for status",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
},3000);
```

The content of 'data' printed in developer tool console is:

```
<html>

<style>
</style>

<head>
</head>

<script>
 var conns=[{num:1,
             id:1,
             Conn:[{type:'ppp',
                    Enable:1,
                    ConnectionStatus:'Disconnected',
                    Name:'CONNECTION_1',
                    Uptime:0,
                    ConnectionError:'TIME_OUT',
                    ..............
                  }]
            },
            {num:2,
             id:2,
             Conn:[{type:'ppp',
                    Enable:1,
                    ConnectionStatus:'Disconnected',
                    Name:'CONNECTION_2',
                    Uptime:0,
                    ConnectionError:'TIME_OUT',
                    ..............
                  }]
           }]
</script>

</html>
```

Need to extract the ConnectionStatus, Name and ConnectionError from this content and display it in respective div in main page.

Comment: Can you change the way you recive the data? If so it would be better if you send the response like `json`, `xml` or other data transfer language.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a different transfer type, however, you could use something like this:

```
function break_out_each_id(){//returns array of indexes where id starts
    var i = 0;
    id_objs = [];
    while data.indexOf('id', i) > -1{
       id_objs[i] = data.indexOf('id', i);
       i++;
    }
    return id_objs
}

function find_values(){//pseudo code
     use the array of indexes from first index to next index
     in that string, do index of each value you are looking for (ConnectionStatus...)
     then parse that line after the ':' to get the value.
     Do this for each index in indexes array
}
```

Sorry for the pseudo code, but this post is getting really long. Like I said, it would be MUCH better to just send the response as JSON (even if it is a stringified version of it). In that case you could just do a simple JSON.parse() and you'd be done.